# Adding a clickable image for a datepicker

Tags: jquery

How can i add an icon next to the textfield,so that when clicking it, the datepicker opens?

```
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $(function() {
   $("#datepicker" ).calendarsPicker({calendar: $.calendars.instance('french')});
  });
  });

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: jQuery click function? [https://api.jquery.com/click/](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

As the [settings docs](http://keith-wood.name/calendarspicker.html) explains, use the `showTrigger` option:

> The element(s) that will trigger a popup datepicker to appear when
>   they are clicked. You can provide either the element itself, a jQuery
>   collection containing the element, a string selector for the desired
>   element, or a string version of the element. The trigger is cloned and
>   placed after the input field (taking right-to-left languages into
>   account).

```
$(selector).calendarsPicker({showTrigger: 
    '<img src="img/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger">'}); 
$(selector).calendarsPicker({showTrigger: '#myicon'});
```

Comment: Updated to reference the plugin you're using.